# Can I have two counter_caches on one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model and an Imagevote model.

```
class Imagevote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :voted, class_name: "User"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :imagevotes, foreign_key: "voted_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reverse_imagevotes, foreign_key: "voter_id", dependent: :destroy
```

Can I set up counter_caches in the User model for both attributes 'voted_count' and 'voter_count'?

If yes, should I do them like this:

```
class Imagevote < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => true
        belongs_to :voted, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => true
```

Will I need to awkwardly name the new attributes 'voteds_count' and 'voters_count' or will the above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it as below:

```
    belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :voted, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => true
```

If you want to specify a custom column name then do it as below:

```
    belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => "voter_count"
    belongs_to :voted, class_name: "User", :counter_cache => "voted_count"
```

Read about **[counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)** option in Rails Guides.

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't realise you could specify a custom column name. Makes it a lot more elegant for me. Thank you so much again Kirti.